# Getting a permission denied error when running _zipit.vbs from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-7, zip, windows-10

I have a batch file that I'd like to use to collect some log files and then zip them up into a directory for the user.  When I run the file I get the error

> _zipIt.vbs(4, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied

This happens on Windows 7 and Windows 10.  I have tried running the .bat as administrator and with administrator permissions. I have run it from cmd and from the windows explorer. I've tried pre-creating the folder(s) and granting full permissions.

Is there a way to avoid this error message?  Here is the code being used

```
Echo off 

Echo Gathering up the SolidWorks Logging files

REM Get XML Debug Dump Directory
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %%A IN ('reg.exe query        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Dassault Systemes\SolidWorksPDM" /v DebugDir') DO set "XMLDIR=%%B"

REM Make the directory and subdirectories for the results
mkdir C:\Collected_Logs
mkdir C:\Collected_Logs\xmldump
mkdir C:\Collected_Logs\IEF
mkdir C:\Collected_Logs\SLW
mkdir C:\Collected_Logs\COG
mkdir C:\Collected_Logs\COG
mkdir C:\SLW_LogFiles
icacls "C:\SLW_LogFiles" /grant %USERNAME%:(OI)(CI)F /T

REM Gather the log files
xcopy /q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\ENOVIASolidWorksInteg C:\Collected_Logs\SLW
xcopy /q C:\%XMLDIR% C:\Collected_Logs\xmldump 
xcopy /q C:\Users\Administrator\ief\logs C:\Collected_Logs\IEF
xcopy /q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\appdata\local\ief C:\Collected_Logs\IEF
xcopy /q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Dassault Systemes\Connector for   SOLIDWORKS" "C:\Collected_Logs\COG"
GOTO ZIPIT

:ZIPIT
set TEMPDIR=C:\tempzip    
mkdir %TEMPDIR% 

icacls "%TEMPDIR%" /grant %USERNAME%: (OI)(CI)F /T

xcopy /q /e C:\Collected_Logs %TEMPDIR%
Echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments > _zipIt.vbs
Echo InputFolder = objArgs(0) >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo ZipFile = objArgs(1) >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile,   True).Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar) >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source) >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo wScript.Sleep 2000 >> _zipIt.vbs
CScript  _zipIt.vbs %TEMPDIR%  C:\SLW_LogFiles

REM Pause briefly to allow ZIPIT to finish
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 600 >NUL

REM Clean up the temporary directories we created
rmdir /S /Q %TEMPDIR%
rmdir /S /Q C:\Collected_Logs

Echo The log files have been zipped up and placed in the directory C:\SLW_LogFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the code.  It was this line

CScript  _zipIt.vbs %TEMPDIR%  C:\SLW_LogFiles

passing the variable TEMPDIR to the CScript was causing the error message Hard coding the path solved the problem

here is the correct code

```
Echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments > _zipIt.vbs
Echo InputFolder = objArgs(0) >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo ZipFile = objArgs(1) >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar) >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source) >> _zipIt.vbs
Echo wScript.Sleep 2000 >> _zipIt.vbs

CScript  _zipIt.vbs  C:\Collected_Logs  C:\SLW_LogFiles\Logs.zip
```